# redirection after uploading a file in php through Android app

Tags: php, android, redirect

I am trying to send an sms to the phone after uploading a file to the server using android application. When I invoke the php script on server side through browser, it works. But when it is invoked through the Android app, I get no results, no error logs either. 
I've tried using both header() of php as well as echo '' method.

Any pointers?

```
<?php
//ob_start();

   $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {


        $username='abc@gmail.com';
        $password='*****';
        $sender='SMSGATEWAYHUB';
        $to='9999999999';
        $message='Test msg';
        //$head='Location:http://login.smsgatewayhub.com/API/WebSMS/Http/v1.0a/index.php?username='; 
        $head='http://login.smsgatewayhub.com/API/WebSMS/Http/v1.0a/index.php?username='; 
        $tail='&reqid=1&format={json|text}&route_id=&callback=&unique=0&sendondate=23-09-2013T07:36:02';
        $text1='&password=';
        $text2='&sender=';
        $text3='&to=';
        $text4='&message=';
        $url=$head.$username.$text1.$password.$text2.$sender.$text3.$to.$text4.$message.$tail;

        echo "<script>window.location='".$url."';</script>";
        //header($url);
        //exit;


   } else{
      echo "fail";
    }
//ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Did you bother checking if an upload actually occurred and actually succeeded? Right now your code is blindly assuming things worked perfectly. What was `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']` contain? If it's non-zero, then the upload failed.

Comment: I have checked that the file has been uploaded successfully. I am a beginner to php. So i don't know how to check the value of $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] as i am uploading the file from phone and it just gets a response code in return indicating whether file upload is successful or not.